# I've used mobile simulators on my website and it looks perfectly fine, but when I test on my iphone there is a ton of missing content

Tags: jquery, html, css, iphone, mobile

I'm a pretty new developer, but this is the first time I've had this issue. I'm testing my website, mattsmobley.com, and on mobile response simulators it appears exactly as I want it to. However, whenever I test on my iPhone 5s and iPhone 6, most of the content is gone.

Sometimes when I haven't accessed mattsmobley.com on my iPhone for a while, I'll bring it up on my phone and the content (videos and descriptions) flashes, then disappears again. The website works perfectly fine on the iPad, I think it must just be something about the small screen?

If you want to check out what the website is supposed to look like, its at mattsmobley.com

Thanks in advance for any help! I know this will probably be a super easy fix for some of you code wizards!

Comment: you didn't check your html for errors and you have many https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fmattsmobley.com%2F it's the same for the css, you have 63 errors and 300+ warnings https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmattsmobley.com%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en  edit: that's odd, I see you are using bootstap css

Comment: er, thanks for the 'help'. someone below actually gave me solid advice as opposed to just whining a bunch about my code

Comment: I'm not whining you idiot. I'm telling you that most of your code is not correct so that's why nothing is working. You also have 53 errors in your css you need to fix. https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=mattsmobley.com&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Comment: Well it was only one thing that wasn't working like I wanted, and the other commenter helped me with that. Regardless, thanks for the link, I'll use it to help clean up my css

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's the `video` tag that may be causing issues. I figured this out by:

1. Open a Safari Browser.
2. Go to Develop -> Enter Responsive Design Mode in the menu.
3. Open the Web Inspector.
4. Observe that when on the iPhones, the videos don't scale down and don't work. In the HTML, the usual video player HTML is not present.

The answer to why this is the case is on [Apple's iOS-Specific Considerations documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1):

> **Optimization for Small Screens**
>
> Currently, Safari optimizes video presentation for the smaller screen
>   on iPhone or iPod touch by playing video using the full screen—video
>   controls appear when the screen is touched, and the video is scaled to
>   fit the screen in portrait or landscape mode. Video is not presented
>   within the webpage. The height and width attributes affect only the
>   space allotted on the webpage, and the controls attribute is ignored.
>   This is true only for Safari on devices with small screens. On Mac OS
>   X, Windows, and iPad, Safari plays video inline, embedded in the
>   webpage.

Comment: ahhh, thank you. i was using a jquery plugin for the video which i guess wasnt supported! i appreciate the help greatly